# HTML select's options get out of parent div

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal and form inside it. form has select tag with options generated from database. it is a long list of names. the problem is it gets out of modal-body container.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="extrusion-modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog  modal-lg" role="dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <form action="Action.cfm" method="POST" class="form-group">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
                    <p>Machine ID = <span class="machine-id"></span></p>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body" style="overflow: visible;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <cfoutput>
                            <input type="hidden" name="actionID" value="">
                            <input type="hidden" name="tMID" value="">
                            <select class="form-control input-lg">
                                <optgroup>
                                    <cfloop query="operator">
                                        <option value="#EmployeeID#" <cfif session.tOperator IS EmployeeID>selected</cfif>>#ename#</option>
                                    </cfloop>
                                </optgroup>
                            </select>
                        </cfoutput>
                    </div>
                </div><!--- /.modal-body --->
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Change Screen</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!--- .modal --->
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('##extrusion-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
      var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
      var actionName = button.data('actionid'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
      var machineID = button.data('tmid'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
      var modal = $(this)
      modal.find('input[name="actionID"]').val(actionName);
      modal.find('input[name="tMID"]').val(machineID);
    })
```

**And the Result on the page:**

[image: Long list of names]

**Using dropdown** as @SGS Venkatesh suggested in one of answers

[image: Using Dropdown]

Any ideas of how to show list inside modal body?

Comment: I've not used "modal-body" before, but don't you still need a "row" div? I think this would sort the padding.

Comment: No. row does nothing

Comment: modal-body or whatever that thing is, probably has default overflow, if you change it to `overflow: auto` it shouldn't pop that out. However, if it still pops out, then it's because the extended part is set to `display: fixed` and there's not much you can do about it.

Comment: I checked every element on chrome dev, there is no dispay fixed

Comment: I'd do a number of tests. Try putting a `<div>` inside the modal-body with borders, then set it 100% height and width and see how much space it takes up. Then put your select thing into the div and see what happens. Maybe update with your results.

Comment: What do you expect/want to happen? The Modal to expand/collapse on when the select gets focus? Always be big enough to accommodate the dropdown?

Comment: I want values of select stays inside parent div(modal-body) and the parent div with exact hight. and verticaly aligned in the middle of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this using Bootstrap's dropdown, and set desirable hight to ul element with overflow-y: scroll or auto.

```
<!-- Single button -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Select Operator<span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Set hight of what? And I need a big font for touch screen display

Comment: Height of the dropdown. I see that you are using bootstrap. Inspect the dropdown and adjust the height of the dropdown accordingly.

Comment: I checked other pages where I use plain CSS without any frameworks, and visited some websites with select tags. All select overlaps parent div. I think there is no way to keep it inside parent div. would be good if....

Comment: You can try using bootstrap dropdowns. Updated my answer with the explanation.

Comment: You can refer this for more explanation. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-single

Comment: nope, I updated my question with new picture, where I included dropdown in my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137107/discussion-between-sgs-venkatesh-and-janatbek-sharsheyev).

Answer (score 0):

maybe this help you?

```
#extrusion-modal .modal-body{
    overflow: hidden
}
```